# Flutter: get the app specific settings so me or user can turn on push notifications on locked phone?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I implemented firebase push notifications in my app but I don't get the messages on a locked phone because the setting is disabled whenever the app is installed.

My question is:

- can I get a list of these settings? (true/false list would be cool)
- can I turn on this setting when the user install the app? (or whenever I want)

See the pictures which settings I need:

[image]

Comment: During initalization of Firebase Messaging, do you request user's permission to notifications?

Comment: Can I do that? I did not find anything like that.

Comment: Yes you can, and you should, otherwise you won't be able to send notifications.

Comment: Did not find anything where I could handle these kind of permissions I show on the pictures. I found only this but even if I set everything true. the "Show on Lock Screen" still disabled: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/permissions/